How to under stand this measure estimate in infinity dimension space $[-1,1]^\mathbb{Z}$
Lemma 4.1. Let $(V_n)$ be random in [-1,1]. Then, except on a set of small measure in [-1,1]$^\mathbb{Z}$,
the following holds
(4.1)
$$\left\|\sum'\ell_nV_n\right\|\geqslant\delta\prod_n(1+\ell^2n^4)^{-1}$$
whenever $0\neq\bar{\ell}=(\ell_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a (finitely supported) sequence of integers.
Proof. Letting $\delta>0$ be a small number, we get clearly
$$\begin{aligned}&\text{mes}\left[\bigcup_{\ell\neq0}\left[\left\|\sum\ell_nV_n\right\|<\delta\prod_n\frac1{(1+\ell_n^2n^4)}\right]\right]\\&\lesssim\delta\sum_{s\geqslant1}\left[\sum_{\ell_s,\ell_{s+1},\cdots}\prod_{n\geqslant s}\frac1{(1+\ell_n^2n^4)}\right]\leqslant\delta\sum_ss^{-2}\left(\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac1{r^2}\right)\left(\prod_{n>s}\right)\left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac1{1+r^2n^4}\right)\\&\lesssim\delta\sum_{s}s^{-2}\prod_{n}\left(1+\frac{C}{n^{4}}\right)\lesssim\delta\end{aligned}$$
proving the claim.
This lemma is in a paper on JFA of Bourgain https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2004.10.019 to get almost all frequencies are non-resonant.
How to understand the first step to get the measure (because I'm not sure is the measure there uses product measure), and is the index $s$ the $1-$norm for $\ell$ to discuss?
